# Intel XDK Alert API not working

Tags: javascript, android, alert, intel, intel-xdk

I am developing a simple app with Intel XDK Framework but i'm not able to use the function called intel.xdk.notification.alert(); It doesn't work and i got no error on the console.

this is the code:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
     intel.xdk.notification.alert("error","Error","Ok");
})
```

Using the console in the Chrome Dev tools i can call the function and see the alert on my Android smartphone but if I i tap on the button nothing happens.
It only works in the emulator, or if i call the function like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
     intel.xdk.notification.alert("error","Error","Ok");
},2000)
```

I tried to search online but nothing seems useful to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Cordova dialogs plugin, instead. We will be deprecating all xdk APis that are redundant, the Cordova equivalent is the dialogs API. Here's the doc page:

-- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/blob/master/doc/index.md

and here's a simple example of their usage:

-- https://github.com/xmnboy/test-third-party-plugin/blob/master/www/js/app.js

Comment: Thanks.
Now i can see the alert box, but it's the standard alert that i get  from a normal web page, with my own title and message.
I would get the native alert notification, that is more beautiful to see.
Is there a way to get it?

Comment: You should be getting native alert boxes with that plugin. You'll only see native alert dialogs if you run an built app on your device, you won't see "native" alerts in the Emulate tab. You will see them in the Debug tab.

Comment: I see "non native" alert and confirm box on my device, using the test tab.

On the docs i found this: "Most Cordova implementations use a native dialog box for this feature, but some platforms use the browser's alert function, which is typically less customizable."
 
Probably this is the reason

Answer (score 2):

The intel.xdk namespace has been deprecated for dialogs. 
Use this `navigator.notification.alert("Message","","Caption");`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var message = "HELLO"
    var title = "HELLO BOX"
    var ok = "OK"
</script>
<div class="button" id="buttonid" onclick="intel.xdk.notification.alert(message, title, ok)">Alert</div>
```

Comment: Please note that this API is no longer supported, use the Cordova Plugin.